# rsyslogd re_match causes segmentation faults

Tags: regex, rsyslog

When I have a rule

```
if ($msg contains "foobah"
 OR re_match($msg, '(authmgr|cli)\[[0-9]+\]:')
)
then {
```

rsyslog ends up throwing a segmentation fault. Even when I comment out the line containing the `re_match` it will still throw a segmentation fault.

```
rsyslogd 8.24.0-34.el7, compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

I would like this rule to match events that contain `authmgr[123]:` or `cli:[456]:`.

Could someone confirm the regex is correctly formatted and explain why commenting out that line causes a segmentation fault?

Comment: rsyslog tries to handle many legacy input formats, so you might try keeping the whole expression `if ... then {` on a single line to help it recognise it as RainerScript. I dont know if `OR` should be lowercase, but that is usually what is seen in the examples.

Comment: I've tried with single and multiple lines, and upper and lower case OR. None of the approaches solves the issue. Does the regex look right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that you need to escape backslash inside strings, so this should work:

```
re_match($msg, '(authmgr|cli)\\[[0-9]+\\]:')
```

In my version of rsyslog, 8.30.0, if you don't do this you get an error message which provides a clue: 
*invalid character ''' in expression - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere?*

There is an [online tool](https://www.rsyslog.com/rainerscript-constant-string-escaper/) to properly escape strings. If you provide `a\b` it generates `a\\b`.